# How do I set a variable that can have multiple values in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

For example I want the variable name where the variable can be one of three strings:

`let name="emma";"mark";"jack";;`

I know this is not the proper way, but I don't have a better idea at the moment. I want to be able to access this variable later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're showing your variable being set to something that looks like 3 strings at the same time. But from your description it sounds like you want a variable that can be assigned one of three different values at different times.

For the first case, @AmbikaE has given an excellent answer.

If you want the second case, you can use a variant type. The string type is pretty much open-ended, but you can define your own type with specific values:

```
type name = Emma | Mark | Jack
```

Leaving aside for now what it means to "assign" a value in OCaml, you can define a variable with one of these three values like this:

```
let x = Mark
```

If you have (say) a function that accepts a value of this type, its parameter can represent any one of the three values (but just one) at each call.

Comment: As I'm guessing @tacocat is quite new to OCaml (apologies if I'm wrong) it may be important to clarify _variable_ vs. the way the term is used elsewhere. When we say `let x = Mark` that is not "variable" in that the value of `x` can never be modified. We can create a new binding to `x` that supercedes that one, but we can't update that binding without using a `ref`.

Comment: Right. As I said I think this is a topic for a different discussion. But it's definitely relevant. IMHO It helps to take things one at a time.

Comment: Fair. I'm always just concerned with the connotation of "variable" given that newcomers to OCaml are unlikely to be newcomers to programming entirely (_I do think it makes a great introduction to programming in general_).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that what you want is actually an array (since I'm unsure what else one might mean by "variable storing multiple values simultaneously"), here are some examples of how they're used in OCaml:

```ml
let names = [| "Emma" ; "Mark" ; "Jack"|] in
print_endline names.(0); (* Prints "Emma" *)

names
|> Array.iter print_endline; (* Prints all the names *)

let name_lengths =
    names
    |> Array.map String.length in
print_int name_lengths.(0) (* Prints length of the string Emma *)
```

If you don't need quick random access and want to be more idiomatic, look into how lists are used in OCaml to do many of the same things you'd traditionally use arrays for in an imperative language.